# Changing a:hover color for links containing accented letters

Tags: html, css

Unsurprisingly I have some links on some html pages. One of them is:

```
<a href="#">Questo &egrave; un link</a>
```

I manage their color and related transitions with the following css rules:

```
a, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
  color: inherit;

  /* transitions */
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
}

a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #003366;
  color: #003366;
}
```

Both with the latest Safari and the latest Chrome the accent is not affected by the changing color. See screenshot, the accent should be blue as the other characters.

[image: white accent, it should be blue]

*EDIT: I forgot to say that I am using a particular font. There is no problem with the default font or other font sets. But I need to use that one (Orbitron).*

Is there any fast way to fix this?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/772rT/ chrome 33

Comment: Same here, perhaps it's the font you're using.

Comment: Doesn't happen in Windows. Have u tried this outside of Mac?

Comment: working for on chrome windows

Comment: Did you use this font to create a webfont via a service like FontSquirrel?

Comment: It is the Orbitron google font, remotely hosted. If I use the default font or some other fonts, the hover is fine. But If I use Orbitron (or other font sets whose names I forgot), the accent stays white. So I can only give up and change font? It is very hard for me to understand why a font containing an accented character refuses to change color. I only tried the browsers on Mac.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/cokanequ/1/edit.  I am pretty sure that this has something to do with the subsets for this font.

Comment: If you look at https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Orbitron you can see that the accented a (à) is included in the charset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font get some glyphes metrics wrong. See:

[image]

The font's ascender is 750 but the glyph's one is 904. As it overflows outside the em square the links are not tall enough to contain some glyphes.

[image]

Your best move would be to use another ([Jura](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Jura) maybe?), as the only fix I can think of has some drawbacks:

```
a {
    display: inline-block; /* so links take line-height as min-height */
    line-height: 1.68em; /* make line-height encompass all (one can hope) glyphes */
}
```

This will prevent line breaks inside of links and increase height of links line boxes. But it solves your problem.